# subquery as the from for mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

What am I doing wrong here?  Trying to use a subquery as my FROM to ensure all joined tables are joined on the correct set.

```
  SELECT
    active_users.username as username,
    active_users.computer_name as computer_name,
    alert.cnt as alerts

  FROM
    (SELECT
        computer_name,
        username
      FROM computers

      INNER JOIN users
        on users.computer_id = computers.computer_id

      WHERE computers.account_id = :cw_account_id AND computers.status = :cw_status
    ) AS active_users

    LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT
          user_id,
          count(*) as cnt
        from logs
        group by user_id
      ) AS alert
      on alert.user_id = active_users.user_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select `user_id` in the first subquery:

```
 SELECT active_users.username as username, active_users.computer_name as computer_name,
        alert.cnt as alerts
 FROM (SELECT user_id, computer_name, username
       FROM computers INNER JOIN
            users
            on users.computer_id = computers.computer_id
       WHERE computers.account_id = :cw_account_id AND computers.status = :cw_status
      ) active_users LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT user_id, count(*) as cnt
       from logs
       group by user_id
      ) alert
      on alert.user_id = active_users.user_id;
```

Comment: awesome... I think you helped me earlier as well so I will ask... can I assume that in this manner that the optimizer will only be reading the necessary rows from the left joined tables since I am joining onto this from subquery?  That was my goal.

Comment: I don't think you can assume that.  When you use `group by` in a subquery, generally all the rows are generated.

Comment: I did some testing and yes, it still reads all the rows from the left joined table. Any ideas on how to eliminate that?  It will certainly become a problem as the tables get larger.  For example, the alert.cnt returns 50, but it reads the entire 7k of rows in the logs table.

Comment: @user756659 . . . You should ask another question and include your data layout, desired results, and queries that you have tried.  The gist of the question would be:  what is the most scalable way to write a query to get the results that I want?